# Extracting a part of an image in LabView

Tags: image-processing, labview

Using the LabView Vision Toolkit I want to extract the average color in a region of the image. But I am having some trouble extracting a part of the image. This is what I have tried:

[image]

But I just seem to get the same image out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a different way to extract a portion of an image that does not need the vision toolkit. Maybe it could be of some use to you:

[image]